# Instantiate class from within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to build a login screen for my application and Im just wondering if this is a suitable way of going about this. I've got it set up so that the Button command checks the credentials and instantiates a new class (which is just a new frame) if they are correct.

```
class Login():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.logo = Label(self.frame)
        self.logo.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

        self.user_name = Label(self.frame, text="Username:")
        self.pw = Label(self.frame, text="Password:")
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self.frame)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self.frame, show="*")

        self.user_name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.pw.grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.entry_1.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.login_button = Button(self.frame, text="Login", command=self.attempt)
        self.login_button.grid(row=5,columnspan=2)

    def attempt(self, *args):
        if self.entry_1.get() == "USER" and self.entry_2.get() == "PASS":
            self.frame.forget()
            load = newFrame(root)
        else:
            print("Try Again")
            self.try_again = Label(self.frame, text="Incorrect Username or Password", bg="#474747", fg="lightgray")
            self.try_again.grid(row=9,columnspan=2)

class newFrame():

    def __init__(self, master2):


        self.a_var = IntVar()
        self.b_var = IntVar()

        frame_main = Frame(master2)
        frame_main.grid(row=2, column=2)

        a_check = ttk.Checkbutton(frame_main,text="A",variable=self.a_var)
        a_check.grid()

        b_check = ttk.Checkbutton(frame_main,text="B",variable=self.b_var)
        b_check.grid()

        frame_bottom = Frame(master2)
        frame_bottom.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.scan_button = Button(frame_bottom, text="Scan", command=MasterScan)
        self.scan_button.grid()

root = Tk()
new = Login(root)
```

My issue is that I'm having a hard time accessing variables from this newly instantiated class.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see in your code right now is that you are making this call:

```
load = newFrame()
```

However, your class is defined as:

```
class newFrame():

    def __init__(self, master2):
```

This is indicating that because of how your `__init__()` is defined, when you try to instantiate `newFrame` it is expecting a parameter, and you are providing none.

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like to know if you even are using master2 in your `__init__()` for the `newFrame()` class. But you might want to look in to that.

As a small bit of extra information, please do not name classes as `newFrame()`. Instead, Go with this format: `NewFrame()`.

Here is the style guide to help you you: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thanks for the response! I went ahead and added 'root' as a parameter to the NewFrame() class. I also included some more code present it the NewFrame() class. This question was actually a result of having trouble accessing the state of the Checkbutton's in that class. Figured i'd sort this out first though.

Comment: Did that help you move a bit forward?

Comment: I actually just wanted to make sure I was on the right track. My real issue here is accessing the Checkbutton variable from outside of the class, as a result of it being instantiated within the first class. I was intending on submitting a second question for that, but if you have any advice id greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If I understood correctly: If you are talking about this call: `a_check = ttk.Checkbutton(frame_main,text="A",variable=self.a_var)`. Then, if you want it to be accessible once you have instantiated newFrame. You simply change it to this: `self.a_check = ttk.Checkbutton(frame_main,text="A",variable=self.a_var)`. Apply this same logic for whatever else you need accessible.